# help with volume notification script, notify-send

Tags: release-freya, ubuntu, notifications

I've been using a script to display a notification via notify-send that showed the volume level on my pc. (this script is called from a keybinding trigger that also lowers/raises the volume, and then reports the current volume with this script). the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /usr/bin/notify-send " " -i notification-audio-volume-high -h int:value:"$(amixer -c "CA0106" -q | grep -A5 Master | grep '%' | cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d']' -f1)" -h string:synchronous:volume
```

This worked well on Ubuntu, but doesn't seem to work properly on elementary. The notification shows, but it doesn't display the volume level, and also a new notification shows every time the button is pressed instead pf refreshing itself.

I know I can fix this because the built-in notification associated with the dedicated volume buttons works perfectly, so I guess I need to adjust my code so it works properly on elementary. can anyone give me a hand with this? how can I send an audio notification in elementary?
Thanks in advance

tldr: 
bassically the command `notify-send " " -h int:value:99 -h string:synchronous:volume` is ignoring the parameter `-h int:value:number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script gave me the solution! you can add `-h string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:script` to my notify-send command and it will work perfectly, thanks.

just writing this here for anyone to see, you can send int:value notifications in elementary OS by typing

```
notify-send " " -h string:synchronous:volume -h int:value:number -h string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:script
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a python script. 
See this snippet: https://paste.debian.net/311290